# vue.js Использование slot-scope внутри slot-scope

Tags: vue.js

Мне нужно написать обертку для другого компонента, который уже сам принимает шаблон через слот. То есть я помещаю шаблон в мой компонент, а он уже в дочерний.

Передаю обертке шаблон для дочернего элемента

```
    <search>
        <template slot="row" scope-slot="props">
            @{{ props }}
        </template>
    </search>
```

Внутри которого уже он должен передать дальше

```
    <multiselect>
        <template slot="option" slot-scope="props">
            <slot></slot>
        </template>
    </multiselect>
```

То есть утка в зайце, слот в слоте. Но проблема в том, что нужно как-то пробросить `props`. Осуществимо ли это вообще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
 <multiselect>
    <template slot="option" slot-scope="props">
        <slot :item="props.item"></slot>
    </template>
</multiselect>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]